# Regex replace name(<keepAnythingHere>) by <kept>.name

Tags: regex

I have a hundred lines with code like

```
name(budget)
name(order)
...
```

I would like to replace it all and have

```
budget.name
order.name
...
```

Anyway to do this?

Comment: show some efforts

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wHmdBc/1

Comment: @erip: it was quick and dirty answer: exactly like the question :) Sure, the spaces are not covered and nested parentheses. There is always ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
^([^()]+)\(([^()]+)\)$
```

with substitution:

```
$2.$1
```

---

- `[^()]+` - matches at least one character except `(` and `)`

https://regex101.com/r/m5lkw6/3

---

Or if `name` word is static at the beginning of each line use the following:

```
^(name)\(([^()]+)\)$
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for showing no effort. I was believing it was not possible =/, didn't even know about grouping. I can tell you that I learned a lot with your response, that regex101 is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @RamondePaulaMarques I would recommend the more explicit `(name)\([^)]+\)` unless you have more than a handful of these that you need to change.

Comment: @Tezra, added a note at the end of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Find by: (name)\((.*)\)

Replace with groups: ($2).($1)